# C++ Beginner. Project Euler 14: Longest Collatz sequence under one million

Tags: c++, beginner, programming-challenge

**Hello, I'm a C++ beginner, learning the language while trying to code Project Euler problems. I'm having trouble coding problem 14, which I'll copy here:**

> The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive
>   integers:
>
> n → n/2 (n is even) n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)
>
> Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following
>   sequence: 13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
>
> It can be seen that this sequence (starting at 13 and finishing at 1)
>   contains 10 terms. Although it has not been proved yet (Collatz
>   Problem), it is thought that all starting numbers finish at 1.
>
> Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?
>
> NOTE: Once the chain starts the terms are allowed to go above one
>   million.

**My program runs fast, and works for smaller values of n, but for some reason I don't understand, it doesn't give the right solution for n = 1 million. I think the mod function % might be the issue in some way for large numbers, or the way i defined the variables, but I can't get it right. 
Would appreciate some help, and thank you for your patience in advance.**

**I wrote this piece of code for it:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double maxvec(int *v,int n){  //gets the max value of a vector
  double elmax;
  elmax=v[0];
  for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
    if(v[i]>elmax) elmax=v[i]; 
  }
  return elmax;
}

double indice(int *v,int n){  //gets the index corresponding to the max value of a vector
  double elmax=v[0];
  double indice;
  indice=0;
  for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
    if(v[i]>elmax){ elmax=v[i];indice=i; }
  }
  return indice;
}

int main(){

  const int n = 1000000;

  long x0;

  int ind;

  int k[n-2];     //vector that contains how many elements are there in the sequence for each initial   number

  for ( int i=2; i<n; i++){   //the numbers we are gonna run through the Collatz sequence (in this case the problem asks for n=1000000)

    k[i-2]=0;         

    x0=i;

      while (x0!=1){          //using the property that all Collatz sequences end in 1

      x0=x0%2 + x0/2*((x0+1)%2)+ 3*x0*(x0%2); //the algorithm for the collatz sequence

      k[i-2] = k[i-2]+1;  //for the final iteration of the while loop, the (i-2)th component contains the information of the number of elements that corresponds to the initial value i

       }

  }

  cout<<maxvec(k,n-2)<<endl; //shows the maximum value of array k

  cout<<indice(k,n-2)+2<<endl; //shows the initial value for the max value of k, which is the solution to the problem

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code works for n = 1000000, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: Also, this cannot be all of your code, it's missing the `#include`, at least one `using` and several other parts to be complete on its own.

Comment: Furthermore, both `maxvec` and `indice` are missing in your code. As-is, this question is unfortunately non-reviewable, but you can fix that :)

Comment: Okay, I added the includes, using, and the two functions. I thought adding the includes and stuff was trivial and not necessary, the functions are pretty basic too. Sorry for that, I'm new here, thanks for baring with me :D You can check that the code works, it just has some bug for large n that I can't figure out!

Comment: As long as you state you'd *appreciate some help* with a correctness problem taken for granted, instead of [looking for open-ended feedback in concrete application of best practices and design pattern use, potential security issues or performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I take this question to be off-topic. (After all, you knew about the million right from the outset.)

Comment: Even if your edit does take the code presented from `doesn't give the right solution for n = 1 million` to *works correctly up to a million and who knows what beyond*, [the edit should *not* have happened](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) (and is bound to be rolled back - do it yourself). The question will stay off topic, one answer given as helpfully as misguidedly notwithstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try and tackle correctness, style and performance in that order

**Corectness**

My initial guess, for wrong results would be you are overflowing an int for long sequences. making x0 an unsigned long I get the longest sequence as 524, for 837799, which matches the results at https://www.dcode.fr/collatz-conjecture . Indeed that sequence contains 2974984576 which will overflow a signed int.

**Style**

Your code is very c-like and has not really used any c++ features other than cout. Some things I would change:

- avoid using namespace std, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice This is generally considered bad practise as it you can get unexpected name collisions. It probably won't cause any real issues on a small project like this, but is a bad habit to get into.
- Prefer stl containers to raw arrays. Stl containers have many advantages over raw arrays. In your case I would make k a std::array, i.e. `std::array< std::size_t,  n-2 > k;` std::arrays are fixed size containers very similar to raw arrays, but don't decay to pointers, provide iterators and to allow easily looping over the elements ( and interacting with the rest of the stl ), among other features.
- Your update of x0 is not very clear/easy to read. I would break this into the two cases with and if/else, and probably make it a separate function. i.e.

```
if( x0%2 )
{
    x0 = 3*x0 + 1;
}
else
{
    x0 = x0/2;
}
```

- Use stl functions rather than writing your own. Another advantage of using stl containers is there are many standard functions that use the containers, which can save you having to write your own. e.g. std::max_element this could simplify your calculation of max value and index.

```
auto maxIt = std::max_element(k.begin(), k.end());
int maxSeq = std::distance(k.begin(), maxIt) + 2;
unsigned long maxValue = k[maxSeq - 2];
```

- Make values unsigned if they cannot be < 0. None of your values should be <0, for clarity it is good practise to make them in this case. The normal way to do this for ints is to use `std::size_t`. This helps clarify the intent of your code.

**Performance**

Your code seems to have pretty good performance and has no trivial performance improvements that I can see. Possibly the updating of x0 can be written more efficiently, but I would change it for clarity reasons, as mentioned above, and profile any possible performance changes from there.

I will note that the sequence does not depend on previous values, so if you reach a value already calculated k for you do not need to calculate the rest of the sequence, but can just add that value. Again you would need to profile whether the cost of doing the extra checks gives an actual improvement.